# Display different fields depending on field value in node template

Tags: 7, nodes, entities, theming, database

I have a field named field_event_type. When creating a node, you can select one of two options for this field from a drop-down list:

- birthday party
- Wedding

I want to be able to display different fields in my node depending on which type of event is selected. So in node--events.tpl.php, my node template, I wrote the following:

```
if ($element['#object']->field_event_type['und'][0]['value'] == 'birthday party' )
   {
      print render($content['field_some_field']);
   }

else
   {
      print render($content['field_some_other_field']);
   }
```

However, this does not seem to be working the way I intended it to, not only is it not displaying the additional field content in either event type, but I'm also getting an error in Drupal about an undefined variable. Is my code incorrect?

Comment: how is it not working the way you intended? what is it doing, what is it not doing?

Comment: Thank you I updated the description of the issue I'm dealing with.

Comment: what undefined variable error are you getting, your code uses 4 variables

Comment: First "undefined variable: element" then "trying to get property of non-object". It doesn't get much more specific than that.

Comment: $element is not a standard variable in a node tpl file - I believe it is used in a field tpl file though. Is it a custom variable you create?

Comment: Thank you, Geoff, this actually answers my question. It works very well once you put it into a field template. If you could please post this as an answer below, I will accept it as the correct answer - thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your use of the $element variable in a page.tpl.php file, I would suspect a typo or error in its use.

You could either continue to use the page.tpl.php but use $node instead, or use a field tpl instead and continue to use $element. Which you choose really depends on the complexity of the set up and where you want the modifications to lie

Answer (score 2):

You may find it easier to use the [Conditional Fields Module](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields):

> Conditional Fields allows you to manage sets of dependencies between
>   fields. When a field is “dependent”, it will only be available for
>   editing and displayed if the state of the “dependee” field matches the
>   right condition. When editing a node (or any other entity type that
>   supports fields, like users and categories), the dependent fields are
>   dynamically modified with the States API. You can, for example, define
>   a custom “Article teaser" field that is shown only if a "Has teaser"
>   checkbox is checked.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, but adding a module is not an option at this time given the way my client has set up his site. The only available option is therefore through the template.